# How can i write the code for making a table in javascript?

Tags: jsp

I've a drop down image.I want to show a table consisting of 3 rows and 1 column in the same page on onmousemove event of the image. Can you please tell me what will be the code for it using javascript in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).
See the [official tutorial](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) for working with `mousemove()`.
And maybe this [article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/linqed/archive/2009/03/04/generating-html-tables-with-jquery.aspx) for actually building the table. 
Or just Google for "jquery build table" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. My next question is how can i make different jquery for different labels? I have 2 labels and i want to make two jquery for them which will be specific to each one. Please suggest me how can i able to do this.

Comment: You can select each one, for example, by id.
Like this:
`<label id="myLabel1">...</label>
<label id="myLabel2">...</label>
$("#myLabel1").doSomething();
$("#myLabel2").doSomething();`